# Getting current customer in custom REST API module

Tags: rest-api, customer-attribute, oauth

I'm trying to build a series of custom requests for an Android app. Specifically I need to make use of the current customer Id in several of my requests. I've only been using magento for a few weeks, and I'm completely stumped. How can I get the current customer session if the session is stored as a cookie in the browser?

My request is just a join of a few tables based on the customerId, but I can't get a valid id in the first place. Does anyone have any insight on how I can leverage the oauth token to get the related customerId? That's the only idea I've had, but I don't know how to go about it.

Any help would be immensely useful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out! Turns out I need to get the token from the header, and query out the customer id from the Oauth_token table. I'm sure there's a better way for me to retrieve the token from the header, but I couldn't find one in the short term.

```
$headerString = $this->getRequest()->getHeader('Authorization');


    $tokenPosition = strpos($headerString, 'oauth_token=');
    $token = null;
    if($tokenPosition !== false){
        $token = substr($headerString, $tokenPosition+13, 32);
    }

    if($token == null){
        $error = 'Authorization Token Not found.';
        throw new Exception($error);
        return null;
    }




    $customerId =  Mage::getModel('oauth/token')->load($token,'token')->getData('customer_id');//Mage::getModel('customer/session')->getData();
```